# Android Map disable 3D mode

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I want to disable 3d view. I can't find anything but only disable building.

This is what i don't want.

[image: This is what i don't want (3D view)]

And this is what i want.

[image: And this is what i want]

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tilt gesture is in the UI Settings for the map.

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this as well:

```
GoogleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false)
```

This will disable 3d buildings on your map to reduce GPU strain.